# How to save a Item Object in Magento to get it back later

Tags: php, magento

I want save

```
$this->_getCart()->getItems()
```

And save it so i can work with the Items after checkout!
After the checkout i want to write the items backk to the cart.

Does anybody has a Idea to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy:

Set items first:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('old_items', serialize($items));
```

and then get them:

```
$items = unserialize(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('old_items'));
```